# Read a CSV-File in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am using QtCreator to build a little UI.
I want to give certain Buttons certain parameters based on a list, that is stored on my computer as for example a text or csv file.

Is it possible to read the contents of this file and extract certain in formation from it to use as button-parameters?

Basically the text file contains the name of the button and a parameter combination, which the program can then load.

Alternatively I would be open to some other solutions using python and sending data from python to the qml file, if that is possible.
I have much more experience with python and don't know a lot about qml and Qt.

Comment: [This link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/91205/reading-text-file-in-qml-file-and-display-it-in-the-scrolling-manner-for-some-time) must help. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Maxim, this helped a lot. 
I used the version with the Http Response.
Now I can read the csv and print it in the console. 

My next step would be to find the individual entries in the "Array"